# Inhomogeneous Laplace equation

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, laplacian

It is well known that the Laplace equation
$$\Delta f=0$$
has many solutions in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but what about the inhomogeneous Laplace equation $$\Delta f=g$$
Can anyone give me a reference which discuss this equation? I want to know the condition on $g$ which makes this equation solvable, in particular, I want to know if the equation is solvable for any smooth $g$.

Comment: I would assume $g$ should also be bounded for physically meaningful solutions...

Comment: The "inhomogeneous Laplace equation" is known as the Poisson equation, and the literature on it is abundant.

Comment: @Jason thanks, I will search for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a starting point, assume that $f \in C_c^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$, let $\Phi(x) = -\frac{1}{2\pi}\log|x|$ and set 
$$
u(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R^2}}\Phi(x - y)f(y)\,dy.
$$
Then one has the following result

> **Theorem**: Let $u$ be as above, then $u \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $-\Delta u = f$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

You can find a proof of this theorem in Evans' PDE book. The Wikipedia page about [Poisson's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_equation) is also a good read if you are relatively new to this kind of problems.

Comment: @chankifung: you are welcome. I want to stress what Jason mentioned in his comment: there is a huge literature on this kind of problems and this is just the tip of the iceberg. Have fun! :)