# 2D inhomogeneous Laplace equation solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, boundary-value-problem

Hi have an equation that looks like this

$
\begin{equation}
 \nabla^2\psi(x,y)=w(x,y)
\end{equation}
$

$w$ is a solution of the homogeneous Laplace equation.

I know that a solution for a 1D inhomogeneous Laplace equation of the form $-\nabla^2U(x)=f(x)$

$
\begin{equation}
 U(x)=\int_{D}\Phi(x-y)f(y)\,dy
\end{equation}
$

With $\Phi(x)=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\log|x|$. This I saw in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2304963/inhomogeneous-laplace-equation).

The exact analytical solution of the integral does not concern me too much because I will solve it numerically, but, there are 2 things I'm concerned with.

1. How do I impose boundary conditions over $\psi(x,y)$ with this solution?
2. Does this approach work for a 2D equation?

The boundary conditions of w are

$
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        &w(x,0)=0\\
        &w(x,b)=0\\
        &w(0,y)=V_1\\
        &w(a,y)=V_2\\
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
$

EDIT

The domain is a rectangle centered at 0 that goes until $b$ on $x$ and goes until $a$ on $y$.

Comment: The "inhomogeneous Laplace equation" you are talking about is known as Poisson equation. Also, when talking about boundary condition it is crucial to specify the domain. So, what is the domain you are studying tour equation in? And who are $V_1$, $V_2$, what is their regularity? With PDEs the devil lies in the details, which in fact are not "details" but pretty important things to specify, but whatever

Comment: V1 and V2 are just constants. should I add the solution of w?

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding, but if $w$ is known and $\psi$ is to be found, should the boundary conditions not be imposed on $\psi$ rather than $w$?